# How to commit and create a branch?

Tags: git, branch, commit

Currently I am working on the master branch and I have some changes hopefully to commit to a new branch which does not exist. Is there any simple way to do this?

BR, Ruochen

Answer (score 1):

```
git brach <branchname>
git checkout <branchname>
git commit
```

You can also add a -b tag to git branch, I believe, to skip the checkout step.

Answer (score 0):

a shortcut for

```
git brach <branchname>
git checkout <branchname>
```

is

```
git checkout -b <branchname>
```

Not sure why you try to create a new branch from master but it is maybe worth having a look at [Git Flow](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/)